# How do i play .asx files in my android application using titanium appcelerator?

Tags: android, titanium, audio-streaming, internet-radio, libmms

I have a URL which downloads an .asx type file when clicked . The file downloaded , streams a live radio and plays it in an audio player . How do i handle this in my android application using titanium appcelerator ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't use asx files, since audio player is a functionallity of Android. You need to use `Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer`

Docs here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer

Comment: I have the same project, I need to play radio stations from this website http://eradioportal.com. Can titanium play this stations?